# display the right section of tableview

Tags: iphone, ios5, tableview, uitableview

I have a table view and I'm toggling its `dataDource` with two `UIButtons` (like tabs).

```
- (IBAction)dataToggler:(id)sender {
    int buttonTag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;

    if(_firstTab.selected && buttonTag != 1){

        AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        myAppDelegate.isFeatured = TRUE;
        [myAppDelegate loadEvents];

        numberOfSections = 1;

        _firstTab.selected = NO;
        _secondTab.selected = YES;

    } else if(_secondTab.selected && buttonTag != 2){

        AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        myAppDelegate.isFeatured = FALSE;
        [myAppDelegate loadEvents];

        numberOfSections = 2;

        _firstTab.selected = YES;
        _secondTab.selected = NO;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Each time when I click on one of the buttons my xml its parsed and added into separate arrays; the arrays contains a list of events (eg. first section with now events and the 2nd one with the rest of them).

The problem which I have is when I have the 2nd button selected I have two section but sometimes my first section is empty so I don't want to display that section if its empty; please take a quick look to my code files...

Right now if my second tab (button) is selected I'm getting an empty table...

My code files are: [myViewController](http://pastie.org/private/lms1gyiwxjc14ve3e620w) and [myAppDelegate](http://pastie.org/private/rkobrv2fgit4zv9guhqva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tableView datasource, implement this method:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 2;
   }


 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     if ( [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] > 0 ) {
         // INSERT YOUR HEADER STRING "times" array here.
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"section %d",section];
     } else {
         return nil;
     }
  }
```

Comment: but for empty case I want to have just one section; actually to have the 2nd one and the first one to disappear if its count is 0...

Comment: already done that, but having a bug when the first tab is selected, getting an empty table with the title of my first section; any clue?

Comment: Ah, in your numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath, you'll need to adjust for the section number being 0 or 1.  In other words, if there is only one section, it will be section 0 in these methods, not section 1.  And if there are 2 sections, they will be section 0 and section 1.

Comment: can you give me an example? based on [my app](http://pastie.org/private/lms1gyiwxjc14ve3e620w)

Comment: ok, you always have 2 sections.  Your numberOfRowsInSection should return 0 for section 0 when it is empty.  If you are seeing the **title** of this section, your titleForHeaderInSection has to also return @"" for the title. See the code sample, above for titleForHeaderInSection.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would probably store my data in a 2d array then you will be able to have the following,

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
  // Return the number of sections.
  return [self.2darray count];
  }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  return [[self.2darray objectAtIndex:section] count];
  }

This will give you the correct number of sections and rows. Rather than trying to mess around with how many sections you have in these methods I would add,

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if([[self.2darray objectAtIndex:section] count] <=0)
        return 0;

  return 44;
  }

This is reasonably neat and tidy and will work irrespective of the number of rows and sections you create. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also depending on what it is you are doing you may want to have two separate data sources each implementing UITableViewDataSource and with between them by changing the datasource of your tableView when the button is toggled. This would be a more specific case and generally I would only do this if the data being represented is different.